# iOS games with random frame drops (including my game)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm almost finishing my iOS game written in Swift + SpriteKit.

It's a quite simple game, 30-32 nodes at max. Only 1 thing has physics. The rest is a few animated clouds (around 6). The CPU usage is around 2-3% and max RAM usage of 75-80MB.

Including that I also get frame drops when changing from one scene to another. Why that could be?
(I'm pre-loading all the textures and sounds during game init, and not on the scenes)

When I use the simulator for 5S up to 6S Plus, I don't see any frame drop in there. So that's weird. Looks like it's not my game but my iPhone 6S?

Now, I do also have other games installed on the same device from different developers, and I frequently get random frame drops too. Lags for 2-3 seconds and then comes back to 60fps.

Does anyone know if this is something that's happening after an X iOS update ? or I was even thinking this my be some kind of background service running that's killing my phone. Call it facebook, whatsapp, messenger, etc.

Is there any way I could possibly check on what's going on?

Comment: It might be wifi problem or Ad framework doing it's stuff or even some background app. I don't witness such behaviour on my devices.

Comment: Damn... i'm struggling with that for weeks, since i started downloading the latest iOS versions.

Comment: Are you running a beta version of iOS?

Comment: No, im running the last 9.3.3. I swear for God is killing my head, don't understand the frame drops to 30-34 fps... i tried so many things already.

Answer (score 0):

Was this caused by the way that newer versions of SpriteKit are defaulting to Metal render mode as compared to OpenGL mode? For example, do your problems go away when PrefersOpenGL=YES is added to Info.plist? I covered a bit of this performance issue in my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader) about a SpriteKit repeat shader. Note that you should only be testing on an actual iOS device, not the simulator.

Comment: I will try adding that, it's a 2D game. And yes, im working on a real iPhone 6S. But in the simulator, it doesn't lag at all..